# How to update a set of pairs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying out operations on sets and i have become stuck on how you could update set of pairs, say I have a set $A$:
$$A = \{(a,3),(b,5),(c,7)\}.$$

If I wanted to add a pair I would use the union of the two sets;
$$A \cup \{(x,8)\}.$$
Or remove one I would use the set difference;
$$A \setminus \{(b,5)\}$$
How do you go about updating $a$, $b$ in the pair $(a,b)$ in set $A$?

Comment: Just take out the old pair and insert the new one. If you do this a lot, you can define a specific, more compact, notation for the operation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, consider to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: If you are after a shorter notation for this, it can be expressed using [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) as $A\triangle\{(b,5),(x,8)\}$. Of course, this is not ideal - from this notation you don't see which pair is replaced by the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard notation for this, but it is clear what to do: simply remove the old pair and then insert the new one:
$$ (A\setminus\{(a,b_1)\})\cup\{(a,b_2)\} $$
or possibly even (if your relation is known to be functional):
$$ \{(x,y)\in A\mid x\neq a\}\cup\{(a,b)\} $$
If you find yourself doing this a lot, you're free to define a more compact notation for it yourself. Just make sure to explain it to your reader before using it.

Comment: "...you're free to define a more compact notation for it yourself. Just make sure to explain it to your reader before using it." - this deserves a +1 on its own.